# Should questions about OS X Yosemite be allowed now it is in public beta?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope, yosemite

I know this question has already been asked, but with the public beta release everyone can access and get Yosemite. There will definitely be some bugs and glitches. Could we ask questions on Yosemite on the main site?

Comment: Shouldn't we block all these naïve questions from undercover Apple agents hunting bad guys who broke their NDA?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because 10.10 has been released now.

Comment: The question was valid at the point of asking

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The public beta for Yosemite has passed and it is now officially released. Ask away.